# Get information from sql file in Python

Tags: python, sql, pycharm, odbc, pyodbc

I have two sql files: data.sql, where is CREATE DATABASE, some CREATE TABLE and also INSERT sentences. Start of the file:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `network` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `network`;
```

I also have a python file, where I want to connect to database:

```
import pyodbc
def connectToDB():
connection = None

while connection is None:
    try:
        connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=data')

    except:
        print ("\n[DB connector]  Error connecting to database. Trying again in 1 sec.")


    time.sleep(1)

return connection
```

This is not my code, I get it on github. But I am a complete beginner with SQL I and have no idea how to use it. Do I have to establish a SQL Server? If so, how? I use PyCharm.

I know it's a dumb question, but I'm really struggling with that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install a database in your local first.
You can try to use some open source solution like MariaDB.
Maybe it has the GUI to create a instance for setting the connection information (user name, password, ...etc).
Please make sure your database works fine then write your python code.
(Connection test and CRUD)

Comment: Nice, thank you! But what is with that DSN? How to connect it to the DB I created in MariaDB?